# Fragment addToBackStack crashes app

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I have a FragmentActivity that loads one custom ListFragment at startup, and replaces it with a new fragment after an item is clicked.

In the fragment activity subclass:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.list_activity, listFragment, "venueListFragment");
        ft.commit();
        ...
}
```

In the list item handler within the ListFragment subclass:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);

    VenueListFragment newFragment = VenueListFragment.newInstance(nextListType, nextRowID);

    ft.replace(R.id.list_activity, newFragment, "venueListFragment");
        ft.addToBackStack(null);                
    ft.commit();
}
```

This works fine after the first fragment, but when I try to click on an item in the 2nd fragment, I get this error from within the internal FragmentManager class:

```
04-03 01:04:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(15016): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 01:04:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(15016): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 01:04:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(15016):    at android.support.v4.app.LoaderManagerImpl.hasRunningLoaders(LoaderManager.java:824)
04-03 01:04:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(15016):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
04-03 01:04:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(15016):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
04-03 01:04:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(15016):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1416)
04-03 01:04:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(15016):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:420)
04-03 01:04:24.999: E/AndroidRuntime(15016):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
```

I noticed if I comment out addToBackStack, the next fragment is loaded fine, but consequently I can no longer navigate backwards.  Also, if I simply wait 5-7 seconds before clicking the next list item, the app doesn't crash, but the cursor loader within the fragment finishes loading way earlier than that since the entire list is already viewable.  In onDestroyView, I explicitly call CursorLoader's cancelLoad() method anyway.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?  Is this a bug in the Android Compatibility Library?

I'm using the latest version of ACL (rev 7) and have the min SDK set to API level 7 (2.1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you do your `commit()` try `executePendingTransactions()`.  `commit()` is an async process and therefore may not execute right away as you expected.

```
ft.commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```